# How to use FULL JOIN and compare variance in Ms.Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
Table_Actual
+----------+--------+
| Product  | Actual |
+----------+--------+
| AAA      |   100  |
| BBB      |   200  |
+----------+--------+

Table_Plan
+----------+--------+
| Product  |  Plan  |
+----------+--------+
| AAA      |   150  |
| CCC      |   250  |
+----------+--------+
```

I need the following result:

```
+----------+--------+--------+----------+
| Product  | Actual |  Plan  | Variance |
+----------+--------+--------+----------+
| AAA      |   100  |   150  |      50  |
| BBB      |   200  |     0  |    -200  |
| CCC      |     0  |   250  |     250  |
+----------+--------+--------+----------+
```

**My query as below:**

```
SELECT table_Actual.Product as Product, Actual, Plan, Plan - Actual AS Variance
    FROM table_Actual
        LEFT JOIN table_Plan ON table_Actual.product = table_Plan.product
UNION
SELECT table_Plan.Product as Product, Actual, Plan, Plan - Actual AS Variance
    FROM table_Actual
        RIGHT JOIN table_Plan ON table_Actual.product = table_Plan.product;
```

result:
Variance value of product AAA and bbb are null value.

Any assistance would be great. Thanks.
TOM

Comment: You can use FULL JOIN rather than LEFT JOIN and get rid off the select after UNION

Comment: I can't use FULL JOIN in Ms.Access 2010.

Comment: @StanislavL Unfortunately that is not supported in Access. OP is right to use Union for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the function [ISNULL()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)...

```
SELECT table_Actual.Product as Product, ISNULL(Actual,0), ISNULL(Plan1,0),ISNULL(Plan1,0)- ISNULL(Actual,0)  AS Variance
    FROM table_Actual
        LEFT JOIN table_Plan ON table_Actual.product = table_Plan.product
UNION
SELECT table_Plan.Product as Product, ISNULL(Actual,0), ISNULL(Plan1,0), ISNULL(Plan1,0)- ISNULL(Actual,0) AS Variance
    FROM table_Actual
        RIGHT JOIN table_Plan ON table_Actual.product = table_Plan.product;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a7d0d0/8)

Comment: Thank you verymuch G one.
Is't work but I use Nz function replace ISNULL in ms.Access query.